# Compute matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let
>   $$\ v_1 = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     2 \\
>     0
>     \end{pmatrix}
> \text{ and } \ v_2 = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     1
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>    We  define $S = \{e_1, e_2\}$ where
>   $$ e_1 = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     0
>     \end{pmatrix} \text{ and }\  e_2 = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     0 \\
>     1
>     \end{pmatrix}$$
>   is the canonical basis.

Let $\alpha$ be a  linear map from  $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$  such that  $$\alpha(v_1) = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }  \alpha(v_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
    5 \\
    2
    \end{pmatrix}$$

> 1) Write  the  matrix  $M_{T,T}(\alpha)$ without computations
>
> 2) Write the base change matrix $C_{S,T}(\alpha)$ without computations
>
> 3) Compute the matrix $C_{T,S}$  and $M_{S,S}(\alpha)$

Could you please give me a hint? For 1) and 2) should I write $M \times S \times T$ and $C\times S\times T$, respectively?

Comment: Did you look up the definitions?  Hint: the column vectors of the representation matrix are the images of the basis.

Comment: $$ That\ is\ to\ say\ 
  T =  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
and\ S =  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
? $$

Comment: I really have no idea how to proceed. I perused the notes I have but no solution comes up to my mind.

Comment: When diagonalizing a matrix, I need to find the eigenvalues. But I am not sure which matrix to diagonalize.

Comment: Has nothing to do with diagonalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment ...  we have 
$$\begin{align}
M_{T,T}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&5\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\\
C_{S,T}&=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\\
C_{T,S}&=C_{S,T}^{-1},\\
\text{and finally}\quad
M_{S,S}&=C_{S,T}M_{T,T}C_{T,S}.
\end{align}$$

As a reminder have a look at the indices: $(S,S)=(S,T),(T,T),(T,S).$
So $C_{T,S}$ transfers an $S$-based vector the corresponding $T$-based vector, $M_{T,T}$ carries out the linear map in $T$-base and finally $C_{S,T}$  changes the coordinates of that mapped vector in base $S$.